# How to Stop li-scroller?

Tags: jquery, scroller

I am using this plugin: [Li-Scroller](http://www.gcmingati.net/wordpress/wp-content/lab/jquery/newsticker/jq-liscroll/scrollanimate.html)
Here is the Code: [Jquery Function Code](http://www.gcmingati.net/wordpress/wp-content/lab/jquery/newsticker/jq-liscroll/jquery.li-scroller.1.0.js)

I there any way I can destroy/stop/restart it (remove all divs and mark up and then start it again) when it is applied to an unordered list via a function.

```
<ul id="ticker01">
    <li><span>10/10/2007</span><a href="#">The first thing ...</a></li>
    <li><span>10/10/2007</span><a href="#">End up doing is ...</a></li>
    <li><span>10/10/2007</span><a href="#">The code that you ...</a></li>
    <!-- eccetera -->
</ul>
```

```js
$("ul#ticker01").liScroll();
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X5Ln7)

Comment: JS FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/X5Ln7/

Comment: you can stop it by calling `$("ul#ticker01").stop();` but it doesn't have any function to start it again - http://jsfiddle.net/X5Ln7/1/

Comment: Thank You. But what about destroying it and removing all its markup tags? I will initialize the function again to restart it.

Comment: Here is a fiddle, but it doesn't initialize plugin again - http://jsfiddle.net/X5Ln7/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To stop and destroy the scroller you just need to "undo" everything the li-scroller adds so you can use the followiing jQuery:

```
$("ul#ticker01")
    .clearQueue().stop()       //stops animation
    .unwrap()                  //removes mask div
    .unwrap()                  //removes tickercontainer div
    .unbind()                  //unbinds any events attached (like hover)
    .removeClass('newsticker') //removes the extra class
    .removeAttr('style');      //removes the height style
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/X5Ln7/6/)

Answer (score 0):

It will stop animation when you hover your mouse on text

```
$("ul#ticker01").liScroll({travelocity: 0.15});
```

Comment: Yes, I know. But I want to destroy the scroller. I mean remove all its markup tags and remove the functionality.